# Jenkins Packaging a exe and dll's to msi

Tags: jenkins, deployment, build, windows-installer, packaging

I'm new to using jenkins.I am working on C# project and using jenkins for continuous build and release. I completed creating builds for my project and got the .exe and dll files. But i need to repackage it(create a msi) before deploying to servers. So can anyone give a stepwise information for rePackaging and tool to be used with jenkins for packaging. I want to automate this process in jenkins CI AND CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repackaging implies you have a third party installer that you want to reverse engineer into a new/better MSI.   You are just packaging not repackaging.

This is a two part question:

1. Author an MSI.  I recommend using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) and [IsWiX](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix) starting with this [tutorial](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials).
2. Build it using Jenkins. WiX supports MSBuild and Jenkins has a [MSBuild PlugIn](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin).  Standard stuff except not that the .WIXPROJ created by IsWiX templates expects you to pass the MSBuild Property  MSIProductVersion.  The correct format for this property is 0-255.0-255.0-65535.  You can tack on a fourth field if you would like but it will be ignored.   The IsWiX project templates are set up for Major Upgrades by default so make sure one of these 3 fields is incremeented with each release. ( 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 2.0.0 )

Comment: By ignored I mean ignored by Windows Installer in terms of MajorUpgrade processing.  It will make it into the Property table of the MSI and show in Programs and Features.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a packaging issue than a Jenkins issue.

Take a look at [WIX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/). I used it successfully in the past with various projects. Integration with Jenkins should be easy. There are 2 options I'm aware of:

1. After installing the WIX toolset, add a new WIX project to your Visual Studio solution. Once configured, commit the new project to your source code repository. Then developers can build .MSI packages on their own development workstation. Assuming you use MSBuild in Jenkins to build your C# project, the new project will "just build" and create .MSI package (remember to install WIX on your Jenkins build server). This is the recommended option.
2. Use WIX's command line utilities to generate MSI in a Jenkins batch step. This is more cumbersome and difficult to debug.

Comment: I heard wix is complicated and not recommended for a beginner . Can you recommend any other tools that can be integrated with jenkins and used for packaging?

Comment: WIX is indeed complicated for a beginner. My first ever setup project was the (now deprecated) build-in Visual Studio "Setup Project". Although it was easier, I got to the point it's limiting me after a short while, and moved on to WIX. What I learned is: Windows Installer and Installers in general are complex, it's not WIX that makes it complex.

Comment: Correct. I have an FOSS tool called IsWiX that has project templates and graphical designers to help with the majority of the WiX authoring.  It's a solution accelerator that helps you get the basic stuff done quickly instead of hitting your head against the wall.  But you are correct, setup is complicated and IsWiX is not meant to be a replacement for eventually learning WiX and MSI.